# Visual Basic: Changing sequence of numbers to display them in reverse

Tags: vba

How do I change this to display number: 2 4 6 8 10 in the order of 10 8 6 4 2

I have tried a lot of stuff, there has got to be a very simple solution to this that I am not seeing.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateSequence()

   'Note each variable must have a type declaration,
   '   else they will be of type Variant
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    Dim S As String

x = InputBox("First Number")
y = InputBox("Second Number")

If Not CheckNum(x) Or Not CheckNum(y) Then
        MsgBox "Both numbers must be positive and less than 100"
        Exit Sub
    End If

If x > y Then 'reverse x and y
    z = y
    y = x
    x = z
End If

For z = x To y
    'check if even and add to string if they are
    If z Mod 2 = 0 Then S = S & vbLf & z
Next z

'Remove the leading separator (vbLf)
S = Mid(S, 2)

MsgBox S

End Sub

Function CheckNum(L As Long) As Boolean
    If L > 0 And L < 100 Then
        CheckNum = True
    Else
        CheckNum = False
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: `For z = y To x Step -1`

Comment: Thank you man, you saved me.